# Issue using escape characters in parameterized SELECT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, escaping

I'm having an issue in SQL Server when I search on fields that contain escape characters. When I search directly, using this code, it works fine:

```
SELECT distinct jobname, @jobname as Parm
FROM SurveyJob
where jobname = 'Head Coach - Women''s Volleyball'
```

But if I use a parameter in the where clause, using the same syntax, I do not get any results back:

```
DECLARE @JobName varchar(150) = 'Head Coach – Women''s Volleyball'

SELECT distinct jobname, @jobname as Parm
FROM SurveyJob
where jobname = @jobname
```

I've tried using REPLACE to strip out the apostrophe from the parameter and the field in the WHERE clause, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @N VARCHAR(20) = 'Women''s Volleyball'
SELECT JobName FROM
(
SELECT JobName = 'Girl''s Volleyball'
UNION SELECT JobName = 'Women''s Volleyball'
UNION SELECT JobName = 'Men''s Volleyball'
UNION SELECT JobName = 'Boy''s Volleyball'
) x
WHERE JobName = @N
PRINT @N
```